# http 404 tomcat4 eclipse MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

I have recently downloading Tomcat 6 and switch the eclipse I was using to the EE edition.I am having trouble getting eclipse to run the JPA project, and I keeping getting the error message HTTP 404. When I open a web browser and type in http://localhost/8080/ I get the tomcat 6 info page so I think the server does work eclipse cannot connect to it.

I have going into the preferences and and made sure the path to the server in the directory was correct..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "your own" instance of tomcat you must specify the location in the server configuration view. Take a look at the screenshot :

[image]

My instance is located at `C:\TOMCT`. Hope that helps

Comment: I switched from serverlets to socket programming